# Python Pandas qcut behavior with # of observations not divisible by # of bins

Tags: python, pandas, ranking-functions

Suppose I had a pandas series of dollar values and wanted to discretize into 9 groups using `qcut`.  The # of observations is not divisible by 9.  SQL Server's `ntile` function has a standard approach for this case:  it makes the first *n* out of 9 groups 1 observation larger than the remaining (9-*n*) groups.

I noticed in pandas that the assignment of which groups had *x* observations vs *x* + 1 observations seemed random.  I tried to decipher the code in algos to figure out how the quantile function deals with this issue but could not figure it out.

I have three related questions:

1. Any pandas developers out there than can explain `qcut`'s behavior?  Is it random which groups get the larger number of observations?
2. Is there a way to force `qcut` to behave similarly to `NTILE` (i.e., first groups get *x* + 1 observations)?
3. If the answer to #2 is no, any ideas on a function that would behave like `NTILE`? (If this is a complicated endeavor, just an outline to your approach would be helpful.)

Here is an example of SQL Server's `NTILE` output.

```
Bin |# Observations
1   26
2   26
3   26
4   26
5   26
6   26
7   26
8   25
9   25
```

Here is pandas:

```
Bin |# Observations
1   26
2   26
3   26
4   25 (Why is this 25 vs others?)
5   26
6   26
7   25 (Why is this 25 vs others?)
8   26
9   26
```

Comment: What input gives this result? Can you share your Series and pandas code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `qcut` behaves like this because it's more accurate. Here is an example:

for the *i*th level, it starts at quantile (*i*-1)*10%:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(26*10+3)
r = pd.qcut(a, 10)
np.bincount(r.labels)
```

the output is:

```
array([27, 26, 26, 26, 27, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27])
```

If you want NTILE, you can calculate the quantiles yourself:

```
n = len(a)
ngroup = 10

counts = np.ones(ngroup, int)*(n//ngroup)
counts[:n%ngroup] += 1

q = np.r_[0, np.cumsum(counts / float(n))]
q[-1] = 1.0
r2 = pd.qcut(a, q)
np.bincount(r2.labels)
```

the output is:

```
array([27, 27, 27, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26])
```

Comment: think i understand.  will the first level always have the larger number of observations with qcut (since (i-1) is meaningless for the first level)?  also, what is the need for q[-1] = 1, is to ensure the range ends at 1 instead of fraction arbitrarily close to 1?